# How to select all rows in ALV OO?

Tags: abap, alv

I've created an ALV with `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID` using the standard PBO/PAI but when I use the method I modify the layout to include checkboxes for every row by this way:

```
g_layout-zebra        = 'X'.
g_layout-cwidth_opt   = 'X'.
g_layout-cwidth_opt   = 'X'.
g_layout-sel_mode     = 'D'.
gv_variant-report     = sy-repid.
gv_variant-username   = sy-uname.
```

[image]

It shows as unchecked by default, how can I select all rows?
And is it possible to select more than one row clicking the checkbox?

Comment: ALV OO could be several technologies. To clarify, you are using `CL_GUI_ALV_GRID`.

Comment: Yes, i'm using CL_GUI_ALV_GRID

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you using `BOX_FNAME`? (it's why it's important to provide a minimal reproducible example, people can't propose a solution which solves your exact issue)

Answer (score 3):

#### Manual way to select all rows

1. Click the very first button in the header row. This will select all rows.
2. Select the first row with the button, scroll to the very end and `Shift+Click` on the select button in the very last row

#### Via ABAP

Use the `set_selected_rows` method. Like

```
lo_alv->set_selected_rows(
  it_row_no = VALUE #( FOR i = 1 THEN i + 1 WHILE i <= lines( lt_sflight ) ( row_id = i ) )
).
```

(Assuming the displayed table is `lt_sflight`)

Additional documentation can be found [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/12a9d91a6c53101489a69be2cd91f0df/7.0.39/en-US/0ab55336d30911d2b467006094192fe3.html).

Comment: I've used the code in the show_data module of PBO and it shows unselected

Comment: @usr1990 Do you have a minimal reproducible example so we can check?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **set_selected_rows** method like this.

```
  data: lr_selections type ref to cl_salv_selections,
        lt_rows       type salv_t_row,
        lv_count      type i.

  describe table gt_table lines lv_count.
  do lv_count times.
    append sy-index to lt_rows.
  enddo.

  lr_selections = gr_alv->get_selections( ).
  lr_selections->set_selected_rows( lt_rows ).
```